# VMware vSphere Client in Parallels 5 Windows 7 VM becomes unusable

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtual-machine, vmware, parallels

Unfortunately there is no VMware vSphere Client available for Mac OS X, so I have to run the client in a Parallels 5 VM with Windows 7.

I always get to a point where the client becomes unusable. If I'm working in the console on a VM I can see "Press Ctrl + Alt to release keyboard and mouse" on the bottom of Parallels. If I press it, the mouse gets released, but as soon if I click somewhere it appears again.

In consequence I have to reboot the whole VM and start the client again. Has anybody also seen that issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt conflicts with the shortcut of Parellel, so you have to change one of them. You can change Parallel's shortcut in Preferences or in Keyboard.

Reference: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?96167-Control-alt-in-Parallels-5 can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.